# How to send different mobile browsers to different sites

Tags: php, android, iphone, html, mobile

I would like to send users who are using a mobile site to my application download page in the App World (Blackberry), Marketplace (android), App Store (iOS). It would find the user_agent and forward them appropriately. Does anyone know where I can find a code like this with all of the user_agents accounted for?

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with this script:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

You can pick different classes of devices and direct them elsewhere.